# Bootstrap grid aligned to left side of page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 for a webapp that I am building, normally when building a website I would either want my page centered (default .container) or have it on a total page width (.container-fluid). In other words the grid system would be a vital part of building the page. With this app I am more interested in using it for everything else but if I can make it work the way I need it, it would be a huge plus.

The app that I am building now does not need the bootstrap grid perse as it has a specific use case at a minimal screen resolution, the app does not have to be scaled for tablet or even a phone.

Just to give you a mental picture, I've build a custom navigation (75px width) that is stuck to the left side of the page. What I would like to have is to have the .container grid system NOT centered but aligned to the menu on the left.

[I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFPU3.jpg)
I know that .container-fluid technically takes care of the MOST part of so that is NOT what I am asking.

The design that I currently want to build is based on the .container centered grid and not the fluid one.

Does anyone have some tips on how to modify bootstrap to make it work the way I described?

Comment: Ok solved it myself, not sure if it is the right way to do it but seems to work. 

I used http://alefeuvre.github.io/foundation-grid-displayer/ and in the bootstrap.css I changed .container value's margin-left: auto; and padding-left to position the grid according to design.

It seems quite easy.